# ¿Cómo puedo manejar múltiples conexiones a un broker MQTT?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt

Soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo pero, aún así me animé a hacer una aplicación de IoT en Flask utilizando paho-mqtt para manejar la conexión al broker y flask-socketio para pasarle al cliente los datos que recibo del broker. Ya tengo algo un poco estructurado y funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Antes de iniciar el servidor de Flask debo pasarle por medio de variables de entorno la configuración para la conexión al broker.
- Cuando inicio sesión en la aplicación, voy a una sección que definí para suscribirme/darme de baja de un **topic** y así poder recibir/dejar de recibir los mensajes que el broker envía cuando tiene un nuevo dato.
- Una vez que estoy suscrito a un **topic** voy a la página inicial de la aplicación y allí es dónde puedo enviar mensajes a través del broker y ver los mensajes que llegan.

El problema con esto es que cuando creo otro usuario e ingreso con ese nuevo usuario a la aplicación, me aparecen los mensajes del broker sin necesidad de haberme suscrito y la idea no es que eso suceda.

Aquí adjunto el código que he hecho:

```
import os
import eventlet
import json
import functools
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import mysql.connector

from werkzeug.security import (
    generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

from flask import (
    Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, session, g
)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

eventlet.monkey_patch()

#// ================================================================= //#

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(16),
    TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True,
    DATABASE_HOST = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
    DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    DATABASE_USER = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
    DATABASE = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE')
)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

#// ================================================================= //#

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user = app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password = app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database = app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

#// ================================================================= //#

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print(f'Connected with result code {str(rc)}')

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    data = dict(
        topic = msg.topic,
        payload = msg.payload.decode()
    )
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)

#// ================================================================= //#

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/auth/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c = get_db()
        error = None
        c.execute(
            'select id from users where username = %s', (username,)
        )
        if not username:
            error = 'Usuario requerido'
        elif not email:
            error = 'Correo requerido'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Contraseña requerida'
        elif c.fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'El usuario ya existe'

        if error is None:
            c.execute(
                'insert into users (username, password, email) values (%s, %s, %s)', (username, generate_password_hash(password), email)
            )
            db.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        flash(error)
    else:
        return render_template('auth/register.html')

@app.route('/auth/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db, c = get_db()
        error = None
        c.execute(
            'select * from users where username = %s', (username,)
        )

        user = c.fetchone()

        if user is None:
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos'

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('main'))

        flash(error)
    else:
        return render_template('auth/login.html')

@app.route('/auth/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

#// ================================================================= //#

@app.before_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')

    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        db, c = get_db()
        c.execute(
            'select * from users where id = %s', (user_id,)
        )
        g.user = c.fetchone()

def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            return view(**kwargs)

    return wrapped_view


#// ================================================================= //#

@app.route('/main')
@login_required
def main():
    @socketio.on('publish')
    def handle_publish(json_str):
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        client.publish(data['topic'], data['message'], int(data['qos']))

    return render_template('dashboard/main.html')

@app.route('/manage_connections')
@login_required
def manage_connections():
    @socketio.on('subscribe')
    def handle_subscribe(json_str):
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        client.subscribe(data['topic'], int(data['qos']))

    @socketio.on('unsubscribe')
    def handler_unsubscribe(json_str):
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        client.unsubscribe(data['topic'])

    return render_template('dashboard/manage_connections.html')

#// ================================================================= //#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(
        os.environ.get('MQTT_USERNAME'),
        os.environ.get('MQTT_PASSWORD')
    )
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(
        os.environ.get('MQTT_BROKER_URL'),
        int(os.environ.get('MQTT_BROKER_PORT'))
    )

    client.loop_start()

    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo hacer esto?

Comment: La verdad que no conozco mucho los paquetes, pero da la sensación de que el problema es que compartes un mismo `client` para toda la app. Si quieres que la subscripción a topics esté ligada a usuarios, tendrás que guardar esta subscripción en la base de datos enlazada al usuario y mostrar/descartar el mensaje en función de esto.

Comment: Gracias @dukebody, voy a intentar organizarlo de esa forma.

Comment: en una aplicación que tengo desarrollado en test lo que tengo que es el primer parámetro del topic el un cliente, así todos los usuarios de un cliente recibirán los mensajes relacionados a ese cliente
cliente 1,  cliente  2 
1/correos/#
2/correos/#